# How parse complex list having inside unlimited dictionary and list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, reddit

I have a function, which returns Reddit comments and its replies upto n-levels, i am facing difficulties how I could extract the comments and replis and save it to CSV. The function is as follow and output is also written

```
def comments_to_dicts(comments):
    results = []  
    for comment in comments:  
        item = {
            "id": comment.id,
            "author": comment.author,
            "up votes": comment.ups,
            "comment-text":comment.body,
        }         
        if len(comment._replies) > 0:
            item["replies"] = comments_to_dicts(comment._replies)
        results.append(item)   
    return results
```

this is the output, i am just displaying only one.

```
[{'id': 'e5bpnup', 'author': Redditor(name='AnxiousSun'), 'up votes': 38, 'comment-text': 'Maps is getting way too bloated and uses way too much rich-media. The explore tab could be its own app. ', 'replies': [{'id': 'e5bu127', 'author': Redditor(name='baspeysp'), 'up votes': 9, 'comment-text': 'Way too bloated, I only use it to locate a place but rarely to do anything about the location, got better apps for that. ', 'replies': [{'id': 'e5c2txt', 'author': Redditor(name='YupSuprise'), 'up votes': 3, 'comment-text': "I haven't heard of any apps for that, mind dropping some recommendations? ", 'replies': [{'id': 'e5chm3o', 'author': Redditor(name='moralesnery'), 'up votes': 2, 'comment-text': "maybe he's talking about another GPS Navigation APP?\n\nIf that's the case we have HERE We Go, Sygic, Tom-Tom, Karta, MAPS.ME, OsmAnd, etc."}]}, {'id': 'e5d9oa2', 'author': Redditor(name='jojo_31'), 'up votes': 1, 'comment-text': 'Yeah me too, the maps themselves kind of suck, rather use OsmAnd'}]}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the replies to a new key in the dictionary, you should append them as separate elements of the `results` list. This will flatten the hierarchical structure so you can save it as a CSV.

```
def comments_to_dicts(comments, parentid = 0):
    results = []  
    for comment in comments:  
        item = {
            "id": comment.id,
            "author": comment.author,
            "up votes": comment.ups,
            "comment-text": comment.body,
            "in-reply-to": parentid
        }         
        results.append(item)
        for reply in comment._replies:
            results += comments_to_dicts(reply, comment.id)
    return results
```

I've added an `in-reply-to` field to the dicts so you can reconstruct the hierarchy from the CSV.